# Run Length Coding Matlab

Tags: matlab, run-length-encoding

I am doing Run Length Coding in Matlab and so far I have implemented the zigzag algorithm and got an array RunLengthCoding:

```
RunLengthCoding = 
(32, 6, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,..., 0)
```

Now I need to run length code this such that I get:

```
(0,6) (0,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1) (3,-1) (2,1) (0,0)
```

This is (length,value), for example (0,6) because there is no 0 and we are at value 6, then when we meet the first 0 we get (1,-1) since there is one 0 and the value after it is -1.

My attempt:

```
RunLengthCoding(1)=[]; %to remove first DC component
relMat = [];
N = 0;
for i = 1:length(RunLengthCoding)-1
     if RunLengthCoding(i)==0;
          if RunLengthCoding(i)==RunLengthCoding(i+1)
               N = N + 1;
          else
              valuecode = RunLengthCoding(i);
              lengthcode =  N;
              relMat = [relMat;  lengthcode valuecode];
              N = 1;
          end
        else
           relMat=[relMat; 0 RunLength(i)];  
    end
```

I know that this does not run! But that is what I have managed so far

Comment: shouldn't the first three pairs be (0,6) (0,-1) (0,-1)?

Comment: You're right, I arranged it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RunLengthCoding = [77   -6  -11 -18 -6  -6  2   -1  4   -1  -1  6   3   1   -1  0   0   0   2   1   2   -1  -1  0   -1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0];

RunLengthCoding(1)=[]; %to remove first DC component
relMat = [];

i = 0;
while i < length(RunLengthCoding)
    i=i+1;
    N = 0;
    while (RunLengthCoding(i)==0 && i < length(RunLengthCoding)) % keep going as long as we encounter zeros
        N=N+1;
        i=i+1;
    end
    relMat = [relMat N RunLengthCoding(i)]; % output the number of zeros we have encountered and the next value
end

if relMat(end)==0
    relMat(end-1)=0;
end
```

Comment: I am getting these errors:

Attempted to access RunLengthCoding(63); index out of bounds because
numel(RunLengthCoding)=62.
and 
Error in CodeR (line 68)
            while RunLengthCoding(i)==0 % keep going as long as we encounter zeros

Comment: now I am getting an error in a previous line of the code, i.e. Error in CodeR (line 54)
        a = cell2mat(blocks(i,j));

Comment: my array ends with 0's but the algorithm should not write anything if it does not find a value > 0 , i.e. I need to have (0,0) since my array ends with 0's as specified in the question

Comment: I have edited my answer so you now get (0,0) as the last entries when your original array ends in a 0.

Comment: Thanks :) However, the algorithm is not working ax expected, I am getting A LOT of values, such as 0     4     0     6     0     6     0   -24     0   -10     1    -5     0     5 etc etc (which already do not seem good)

Comment: well your worst-case `relMat` length would be twice the length of `RunLengthCoding` (which happens when a single zero alternates with a single non-zero value at each step). Is it longer than that? Could you perhaps add the `RunLengthCoding` vector you are using to your question so it is easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: I am using : 77 -6 -11 -18 -6 -6 2 -1 4 -1 -1 6 3 1 -1 0 0 0 2 1 2 -1 -1 0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. I didn't undserstand the complexity problem, the output should be as I explained on the simpler problem in the question (for that question obviously)

Comment: Alright, when I put that vector in I get a 1x48 result vector which looks OK to me - it ends with [27 0]. I am not sure what you mean with the 'complexity problem', could you elaborate on that?

Comment: i need it to end with 0,0 ( it must not say the no of 0's (i.e.27) if there is not a number after the 0's). Also it is starting from 0 11, why is it skipping 0 6? I need to skip the first component (77) only

Comment: There was a typo in my last line of code. I have updated the entire code in my answer. For me this yields [0 6] as the first two entries, and ends in [0 0].

Comment: @user1930901 The last code (0,0) is a bit confusing. I understand it's not linked with the number of final zeroes, but do you need it even if there is no zero at the end of the input vector?

Comment: No if at the end there is for example 1 I would need (0,1), but when it sees a zero it must keep counting until an integer is encountered (that is not a zero) and since in my case it never finds an integer after those zeros the output should be (0,0).

Comment: no it outputs (27,0) for the last 0's when it should output (0 0) and it skips the second as well ,i.e. -6

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire code as it is listed in my answer now? For me that yields: 0    -6     0   -11     0   -18     0    -6     0    -6     0     2     0    -1     0     4     0    -1     0 -1     0     6     0     3     0     1     0    -1     3     2     0     1     0     2     0    -1     0    -1 1    -1     0     1     6    -1     2     1     0     0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing such a complex loop, you can do the whole thing without any loop, in the following manner:

```
% RunLengthCoding is the input row vector
rlc_m = (RunLengthCoding~=0);
relmat = [diff(find(rlc_m))-1 ; RunLengthCoding([false,rlc_m(2:end)])];
```

I've put the output in two rows, but you can get a single row vector with `relmat(:).'`. I think it's an easier way to get the rlc.

**Explanation:** First I create the mask of all non-zero values, stored into `rlc_m`. Then the trick is the following: the non-zero values (2nd row) is the elements of the input where I mask the very first one. To grab the number of 0 between two numbers, I compute the difference of indexes of non-zeros elements in the input array, minus 1 to count the number of elements strictly between two indexes.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error: Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in CodeR (line 79)
        relmat = [diff(find(rlc_m))-1 ;